# Docker Container can ping, but cannot telnet from Virutal Machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, virtualbox, bridge, docker

I have a host (Ubuntu), a docker container (centOS), a virtual machine (centOS). 

- My Host has 2 interfaces, one is eth0 "192.168.0.4", one is docker0 "172.17.42.1"

- My docker container have IP "172.17.0.1". It has a service bind on port 80.

- On Virtual Machine, I use bridge adapter with docker0 and I config  "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0" file like this:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=08:00:27:72:40:6B
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=172.17.0.250
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
```

From host, I telnet to container's service

```
$ telnet 172.17.0.1 80
Trying 172.17.0.1...
Connected to 172.17.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It is OK!

 ***BUT, From Virtual Machine I cannot telnet to it***

```
$ telnet 172.17.0.1 80
Trying 172.17.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

From my Virtual Machine, I can ping the Docker Container

```
$ ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
```

**So, How to telnet to my service on Docker Container?**

Comment: I flushed all iptables' rule. But I cannot telnet.

Comment: Have you checked with netstat to see if there is something listening on that port? (netstat -an)

Comment: @Rob: on my Docker Container, there is only my service on port 80.

Comment: When a docker container is start, my host create a virtual interface called vethXXXX (eg: vethf345a6e). I used vethXXXX for bridge adapter of my VM. And everything is OK, the problem is resolved! BUT I don't understand about that.